# How to type the pipe character | in Ubuntu 22.04.3 using a Mac?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, mac, pipe

I am trying to type the pipe character | in Ubuntu using a Macbook, but am unable to do so.

I configured the keyboard to the correct language when booting Ubuntu from the VM, but am unsure if this defaults to Windows keyboards. Does anyone know if I need to configure anything further in order to use my Mac keyboard as usuall or if there are only certain types of layouts that are supported?

Comment: "Does anyone know if I need to configure anything further in order to use my Mac keyboard as usuall " Generally there is no need. IIRC hardware during virualization is handeld by the host OS. not the guest OS so this might be a windows or vmware issue and not Ubuntu.

Comment: Which keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: What is the "correct language" for you? The location of the pipe depends on the language and keyboard layout.

Comment: I know the position and am able to use it when I ssh into the vm using the mac shell, but it just does not seem to work in the Ubuntu vm...